# Lombok @Builder.Default forcing default Optional value to null

Tags: java-8, jackson, option-type, lombok

In my code I have a class that looks like the following

```
public enum Test {
    VALUE1,
    VALUE2
}

@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class MyClass {
  @JsonProperty(name = "test")
  private Optional<Test> test = Optional.empty();

}
```

This works fine, but it gives the following error:

> warning: @Builder will ignore the initializing expression entirely.

Great, let me add `@Builder.Default`...

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class MyClass {
  @Builder.Default
  @JsonProperty(name = "test", required = true)
  private Optional<Test> test = Optional.empty();  
}
```

This fixes the error, but now the `test` value is forced null when it doesn't exist instead of `Optional.empty`. I'd like to keep the Optional pattern and let the user of the object decide how they want to handle the Optional, not Lombok or Jackson.

Is there a way to make this work so the default remains `Optional.empty()`? If not, is there a way I can ignore this warning since it can't be fixed?

**EDIT:**

Imagine we pass a payload to some endpoint that is empty (because we want to test the optional of the *only* value in the object)

`POST /my/end/point`

and the payload would be `{}`

We then use Jackson to get the object back

`MyClass result = mapper.readValue(payload, MyClass.class);`

When we look at the resulting object, we will find that `MyClass.test` is `null` rather than `Optional.empty()` as expected when `@Builder.Default` is used. Otherwise, we get the warning above, but the default value is correctly specified as `Optional.empty()`.

Comment: I guess I am "that guy" who would rather write boiler plate code than use a third party tool that requires and IDE plugin-in (which realistically could go out of support at any point in time) do things for me. You've only managed to decrease my desire to ever use Lombok.

Comment: @JacobBlanton I appreciate your feedback, however writing boilerplate is prone to errors. In my years as a developer I can attribute a lot of really dumb errors to the copy/paste nature of writing boilerplate. Maybe you're ever-vigilant, but I sure am not. There's a reason these libraries are popular, you may want to give them a second chance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a code style issue. Letting the Lombok to generate getter/setter/constructor/builder for an optional field results in this:

```
public MyClass(Optional<Test> test) {
    this.test = test;
}

public Optional<Test> getTest() {
    return test;
}

public void setTest(Optional<Test> test) {
    this.test = test;
}

// ... imagine Builder here ...
```

The getter is ok, but the constructor, the setter, and the Builder become very inconvenient to use. You have to wrap a `Test` using one of the static methods on `Optional` like this:

```
// If value is known
myClass.setTest(Optional.of(Test.VALUE1));

// If initializing with a variable which maybe null
myClass.setTest(Optional.ofNullable(anotherTest));
```

It's ugly. There is a better way.
I assume that you only want the `Optional` for the return type on the getter, so provide your own getter implementation, forcing Lombok to not generate it’s own.

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class MyClass {

    @JsonProperty(name = "test", required = true)
    private Test test;

    public Optional<Test> getTest() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(test);
    }
}
```

<sup>Source of Wisdom: [Optionals and Lombok @ Medium](https://medium.com/@johnpang/optionals-and-lombok-a414639dca1e)</sup>

Comment: I had selected this as the answer but I had to unselect it. This is a great write up, but I think the problem exists in the setter Jackson is using. In this case, we need to find a way to generate a new setter that sets the value to something other than null (the null is, of course, coming from jackson). I'll mark your answer if you complete it such that the sample payload returns the expected result (will update the post in a second).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a builder, I’d suggest switching to `@Value`, making your class immutable. You can use the `toBuilder` option if you want to make further changes after building the object.

As for the argument that Optional setters are “ugly”, I think they miss the point of Optional. If you are using Optionals holistically, then the production code that is doing the setting will already have an optional. Requiring it for the setter or builder argument means the caller has to make a determination about whether the argument could be null or not. This is a good thing! The caller will have to consider and deal with possible nulls, perhaps refactoring so that the layer above has to also provide an optional, and so on.

In practice, nullable values most often come from a deserialisation framework like Jackson, which can do the wrapping for you. That means you don’t actually have to deal with the “ugly” very often.

Never skip on something that can remove bugs from your code just because someone says it is ugly. Code with fewer bugs is beautiful.